# TableView cell: Constraint change conflicts tableView.endUpdates()

Tags: swift, tableview, constraints

I have a messaging application written in Swift.

---

It does have message bubbles: `if the message is longer than 200 chars` it is being shortened.

**Whenever the user clicks on a message it gets selected:**

- If the message was shortened, I replace the text with the original long text: Therefore I need to call `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()`
- Plus I have to change the timeLabel's height constraint with `UIView.animate()`

**But the two seems to conflict each other, and makes a weird animation:** (watch the end)

https://youtu.be/QLGtUg1AmFw

Code:

```
func selectWorldMessage(indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? WorldMessageCell {

        cell.messageLabel.text = data[indexPath.row].originalMessage
        self.lastContentOffsetY = self.tableView.contentOffset.y
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {


            cell.timeLabelHeightConstraint.constant = 18                

            cell.layoutIfNeeded()


        }

        self.tableView.endUpdates()
        self.lastContentOffsetY = nil
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()

         WorldMessageIdsStore.shared.nearby.saveCellHeight(indexPath: indexPath, height: cell.frame.size.height, expanded : true, depending: indexPath.section == 1 ? true : false )





    }
}
@objc func deselectSelectedWorldMessage(){
    if (currentSelectedIndexPath == nil){
        return
    }
    let indexPath = currentSelectedIndexPath!

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? WorldMessageCell {

        cell.messageLabel.text = data[indexPath.row].shortenedMessage

        self.lastContentOffsetY = self.tableView.contentOffset.y
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
            cell.timeLabelHeightConstraint.constant = 0                

            cell.layoutIfNeeded()



        }

        self.tableView.endUpdates()
        self.lastContentOffsetY = nil
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()


    }



    currentSelectedIndexPath = nil
}
```

Is there a way to animate cell height change & constraint change in the same time?

I can not place `self.tableView.beginUpdates()` and `self.tableView.endUpdates()` in the `UIView.animate(){ ... }` part, because it would cause the new appearing rows to flicker.

.
.
.

### **UPDATE 1**

So If I palce the `self.tableView.beginUpdates()` and `self.tableView.endUpdates()` inside the `UIView.animate(){ ... }`, then the animation works fine. But as I mentioned it causes flicker when new rows are appearing.

**Video:**

https://youtu.be/8Sex3DoESkQ

### **UPDATE 2 !!**

So If I set the `UIview.animate`'s duration to `0.3` everything works fine. I don't really understand why.

Answer (score 0):

This animation can be sticky.

I think your main problem here is bubble shrinking more then it should. If you run your animation in **slow animation** mode (By the way, the simulator has this option, very useful for debugging) you will notice:

[image: Bubble shrink]

To sort this out, you can make your label **vertical content compression resistants**
higher, and check label has top and bottom constraints with Hi priority too, so it would not get cut this way.

https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/ios-content-hugging-and-content-compression-resistance-priorities-476fb5828ef

Comment: Thank you for your response! It is set to higher: I think the problem is that the app can not animate the two animations at the same time. I Updated the main post!

Comment: @AndrasKarpati You do not need to animate the 2 constraints. If the Bubble height is the same, and you only change It's the origin, your animation would look good. The problem you have is because the height is changing, when it should not

Comment: did what you suggested, but still it is not working :/

Answer (score 0):

**Try using the following code to overcome flicking problem**

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: UITableView.ScrollPosition.middle, animated: true)
```

**Alternative solution** 
try using this handsome method to update your cell with animation instead of beginUpdates() and endUpdates() methods

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.bottom )
```